# Change A Devise Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.4.1

I would like to change the messages sentences that appear in case of an error or a notification in the devise_error_messages. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Devise messages are in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`, so you can override the messages you want

Comment: restart the server after changes made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corresponding I18n translation-files are located in `config/locales` folder  (`devise.en.yml` for ex). You can make changes there.

Comment: Sorry, I've realized my mistake. I changed the message in the gem and not in the config/locales of the project. Thank you.